# Jquery Scroll Full Screen Background

Tags: jquery, scroll, fade

I have a site that will have multiple full screen backgrounds (well, 100% width and set height of 1024px)

What this script does (or should do) is fade out one div and fade in the other whilst you are scrolling down.

However, to make life easier am using the nth-child selector - this works great on the first two divs, but not on any after that.

Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var didScroll = false;
var $window = $(window);

$(window).scroll(function(){
  didScroll = true;
});

window.setInterval(function () {
if (didScroll) {
  if (1-$window.scrollTop()/1024 > -10) {
      $('.item:nth-child(even)').css({opacity: 1-$window.scrollTop()/1024});
      $('.item:nth-child(odd)').css({opacity: 1*$window.scrollTop()/1024});
  }
  didScroll = false;
}
}, 50);
});
```

Comment: can you add fiddle so that exactly i got to knw what you need ??

Comment: You'll probably want to wrap the elements (icons?) in a container. Then you could just do `$('.container').children()`. Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 1):

nth-child is **not** limited to even or odd, just use any number you want. For example:

```
$(".item:nth-child(3)").css({opacity: 1-$window.scrollTop()/1024})
```

**EDIT:**

Now something like this should work:

```
  $('.item:nth-child(1)').css({opacity: 1-$window.scrollTop()/1024});
  $('.item:nth-child(2)').css({opacity: 2-$window.scrollTop()/1024});
  $('.item:nth-child(3)').css({opacity: 3-$window.scrollTop()/1024});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yDuh7/
Or another one: http://jsfiddle.net/yDuh7/1/

Comment: makes no difference, still only seems to fade the first two divs

Comment: OK, it seems to be doing what it is suppose to - but it does it at the same time, regardless of where you are at scrolling. So, it fades out div 1 & 3 as you scroll, and div 2 & 4 fades in as you scroll.

Comment: @Palemo check my edit, its a bit different than your first example but it should fade out one background after another.

Comment: works well! only thing is it doesnt fade in the photo - i used your first jsfiddle link, as the second didnt work for me for some reason. JSFiddle of most of the parts: http://jsfiddle.net/wgjt4/ - jquery backstretch used to attach full screen background to .one, .two etc